# Unhealthy worker process recycle by IIS

Tags: iis

Does IIS automatically recyclea worker process which has been deemed as unhealthy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can configure to recycle based on our needs.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179(v=WS.10).aspx

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling/periodicRestart

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725836(v=WS.10).aspx